# asp.net web api authorization framework Is there anyway to dynamically change roles at runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-authorization

Is there anyway to change roles at runtime. 
https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Customizing-ASPNET-Authentication-with-Identity/02 as he asked at 32:43

Comment: for Example If you were on holiday but you want to authorize your co-assistant to approve some propositions on your system.
Do you think this is the best way to give your account information to your co-assistant.
I have an idea like a role for each controller for this kind of situation to change the role dynamicaly.
For Example,
Aproval role for aproval method.
Send proposal role for sending proposal.
I think i can  add or remove those roles dynamicaly
But this would be a long process for the user.
I did not like to add individual roles. I would like to learn how to do it.